# How to capture click ID all the times with Google Tag Manger?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-tag-manager

I created a trigger which captures clicks on buttons using Google Tag Manager, and my buttons have nested divs and they look like this in dev tools:
[image]

and they render like this:

[image]

I want to capture the ID on the parent div i.e. `confirm-09:00:22:00` in the GTM variable. The problem I am facing is that if a user clicks on padding around `Confirm Timeslot` text, the ID is captured correctly, but if the clicks happens on the `Confirm Timeslot` text itself, the ID is empty. How can I make sure that the ID is always captured regardless of where user clicked on the button? Thanks

Comment: Try https://medium.com/@postman31/conquer-nested-elements-clicks-tracking-in-gtm-71195a3f609b

Comment: You can have a CJS variable that would analyze the {{Click Element}} and determine what to do from there. If you want help with that, paste your html as text in your question.